# Water Jug Problem in python to fill equal amount of water in same capacity of jugs

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, equals, water-jug-problem

write a program to simulate water jug problem with 2 empty jugs having capacity of 4 gallons each. the program must enlist series of steps that can consequently fill both jugs with 2 gallon water

Comment: Just google it. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/water-jug-problem-using-memoization/

Comment: This isn't a question. Are you asking for help on an assignment - if so ask for specific help on the areas you're struggling with and not "please do my work for me" which is how the question comes across?

Comment: This isn't chegg.com

Comment: Water jug problem cannot be solved with two jugs of equal volume.